# how to correctly implement kotlin coroutines with Paging Library?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an android app in which i want to implement Kotlin Couroutines, the confusion I am having is where do I use the coroutine. I have the viewModel as-

```
class PostViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var postPagedList: LiveData<PagedList<UnsplashImageDetails>>? = null
    private var postLiveDataSource: LiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Int, UnsplashImageDetails>>? = null

    var popularPagedList: LiveData<PagedList<UnsplashImageDetails>>? = null
    private var popularLiveDataSource: LiveData<PageKeyedDataSource<Int, UnsplashImageDetails>>? = null

    init {
        val postDataSourceFactory = PostDataSourceFactory()
        val popularDataSourceFactory = PopularDataSourceFactory()

        postLiveDataSource = postDataSourceFactory.getPostLiveDataSource()
        popularLiveDataSource = popularDataSourceFactory.getPopularLiveDataSource()

        val config: PagedList.Config = (PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(PostDataSource().PAGE_SIZE).build()
        val configPop: PagedList.Config = (PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(PopularDataSource().PAGE_SIZE).build()

        postPagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(postDataSourceFactory, config).build()
        popularPagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(popularDataSourceFactory, configPop).build()
    }
}
```

where should I use the async method, within this activity or in the repository class where I fetch data through retrofit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, coroutines should fire in the `PostDataSource`.If you are wondering whether you should use `GlobalScope` there, the answer is not. There is a more elegant way of doing this. You should find a way for canceling jobs to prevent memory leaks also. That's why I wrote [this article](https://coroutinedispatcher.blogspot.com/2019/07/manage-network-states-with-paging.html) here, which solves this particular problem.

You should find a way to manage coroutines from your `ViewModel` , but you should fire them in the `DataSource` .

The best way to do it.

Create a data class:

```
data class Listing<T>(
    val pagedList: LiveData<PagedList<T>>,
    val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState>, //initial state
    val refreshState: LiveData<NetworkState>, // second state, after first data loaded
    val refresh: () -> Unit, // signal the data source to stop loading, and notify its callback
    val retry: () -> Unit,  // remake the call
    val clearCoroutineJobs: () -> Unit // the way to stop jobs from running since no lifecycle provided )

enum class Status {
    RUNNING,
    SUCCESS,
    FAILED
}

@Suppress("DataClassPrivateConstructor")
data class NetworkState private constructor(
    val status: Status,
    val msg: String? = null
) {
    companion object {
        val LOADED =
            NetworkState(Status.SUCCESS)
        val LOADING =
            NetworkState(Status.RUNNING)

        fun error(msg: String?) = NetworkState(
            Status.FAILED,
            msg
        )
    }
}
```

And then, your data source factory should be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/coroutineDispatcher/57ae677dcdefcca551e5ca5d21a2210e#file-newsdatasource-kt).

What you benefit from this approach is that you can cancel jobs in the `onCleared` method in the `ViewModel`:

```
override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        //finish the coroutines opened jobs
        listing.clearCoroutineJobs.invoke()
    }
```

Note that this is also a guide provided by Igit, in this [github repo](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample).

I do agree that the solution should have been simpler, but if you think about it, coroutines and concurrency overall has nothing to do with simplicity, you are dealing with threads here.

Comment: I like this answer, but have a question for you @coroutineDispatcher.  Android's docs say to use the synchronous version of Retrofit's APIs (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging#network-only-data-arch).  Do you know why they recommend doing that?  Is there any "harm" to doing it with Coroutines like you and the OP are doing?

Comment: Looks like it uses callbacks. There is no saying that prevents to use coroutines but it could be just because of handling cancelation is a little hard from DataSource

Comment: Thanks to @coroutineDispatcher. I have written an abstract class which handles all Coroutine stuffs and you just need implement 3 suspend methods. you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/mirmilad/c488276baf255454689ddbfd78dcf65b#file-coroutinepagekeyeddatasource-kt).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. First you might have different types of data. Second the `PagedKeyDataSource` is not the only component used, which would make you write 3 more abstract classes for different cases. It complicates things a lot.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher: I didn't get your meaning by "different types of data". May I know more details or an example that is impossible to implement by this abstract class?
I know there are other components as well. This is the idea and I would like to make it mature first and then apply to the other components.

Comment: check paging lib datasource types

Comment: Can viewModelScope of ViewModel be used instead of manual jobs cancelling?

Comment: Not sure, the cancelation is happening in different class. That would bring a leak